# Finding the values of $k$ for which $x + 2$ is a factor of $(x + 1)^5 + (5x + k)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Find the values of $k$ for which $x + 2$ is a factor of $(x + 1)^5 + (5x + k)^3$.

Here is my attempt at solving this question:

$$ \text{Let } f(x) = (x + 1)^5 + (5x + k)^3 $$

$$ \text{Since } x + 2 \text{ is a factor of } f(x), f(-2) = 0, \text{ i.e.} $$

\begin{align}
[(-2) + 1]^5 + [5(-2) + k]^3 &= 0 \\
(-2 + 1)^5 + (-10 + k)^3 &= 0 \\
(-1)^5 + (-10 + k)(-10 + k)(-10 + k) &= 0 \\
-1 + (-10 + k)[-10(-10 + k) + k(-10 + k)] &= 0 \\
-1 + (-10 + k)(100 - 10k - 10k + k^2) &= 0 \\
-1 + (-10 + k)(100 - 20k + k^2) &= 0 \\
-1 + k(100 - 20k + k^2) -10(100 - 20k + k^2) &= 0 \\
-1 + 100k - 20k^2 + k^3 - 1000 + 200k - 10k^2 &= 0 \\
k^3 - 20k^2 - 10k^2 + 200k + 100k - 1000 - 1 &= 0 \\
k^3 - 30k^2 + 300k - 1001 &= 0
\end{align}

Was my approach correct? How should I continue my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expand the power : as you said, you want to find $k$ such that
$$(k-10)^3=1$$

which is equivalent to
$$k-10=1$$

so
$$k=11$$

Comment: Very simple and easy approach

Answer (score -1):

Your first insight is exactly the idea, though the algebra would be easier without the expansion you do:

$$f(-2) = 0 \implies -1 + (k - 10)^3 = 0 \implies (k - 10)^3 = 1$$

If your problem only asks for real solutions of $k$, then it is clear that $k = 11$ is the only solution. However, if complex numbers are allowed, you will need to consider the case where $k - 10$ is a complex third root of unity, i.e. $k - 10 = \frac{-1}{ 2} + \frac{\sqrt 3}{ 2} i$ or $k - 10 = \frac{-1}{ 2} - \frac{\sqrt 3}{ 2} i$.

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: Why not? What about it would you like me to fix?